# Extending typescript interface from another module

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, typescript-typings

I am using Highcharts typings, and  I need to extend several object/interfaces it defines to add some properties of my own. E.g.

```
declare namespace Chart {  
  interface ChartOptions extends Highcharts.ChartOptions {
    series: ResourceSeries[];
  }
}
```

chart.component.ts

```
import ChartOptions = Chart.ChartOptions;
export class ChartComponent {
}
```

This fails giving me "Chart is not defined". Meanwhile if used in another (master) module which uses the ChartComponent directive, the import works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I cannot use namespaces inside modules. Switching to normal interface exports in a separate non-d.ts file worked, as now every interface is packed with the rest of the module and can be imported as such.

Answer (score 3):

How about importing the interface, extending it and re-exporting?

```
// chart-options.extended.ts
import { ChartOptions as ChartOptionsBase } from 'highcharts'

interface ChartOptionsExtended extends ChartOptionsBase {
    extensionProperty: string
}

export { ChartOptionsExtended as ChartOptions }
```

Not sure what typings/types system you are using, but I'm using the Typescript 2.0 style, which doesn't use "ambient" typings:

```
npm install --save highcharts @types/highcharts
```

Comment: I am currently supplying a typings.d.ts file in each module, each file declaring a namespace which has the interfaces used in that module (or can be used when another component uses this module).

Comment: I am relatively new to Typescript and a bit confused about the various typings styles, can you recommend a way to declare the various interfaces?